# awk - print a field n number of fields away from a matched field

Tags: awk

This works perfectly:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~/mystring/) print $1, $i}'
```

But I also want to print the 2nd field away from the $i field.

Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fairly simple :)

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~/mystring/) print $1, $i, $(i+2)}'
```